# Best practice for developing a WebService in SharePoint?

Tags: wspbuilder, solution-package, web-services, installation, wsdl

I've followed the following steps to build a WebService in SharePoint:

1. Created a new project using WSPBuilder.
2. Added a 'WebService' (Add a new web service to the layouts folder)
3. Do a WSBBuilder "Deploy"
4. The WebService is accessible via http://server/_layouts/MyWebService.asmx

Is this correct ? Or should I follow the steps described at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx) to create my own **.wsdl** / **.disco** files and deploy them to **/_vti_bin** to make my WebService accessible via http://server/_vti_bin/MyWebService.asmx ? 
(Note : the manual steps from MSDN can be automated using [SPDev](http://www.crsw.com/spdev/Wiki%20Pages/GenWS.aspx).

I also found this blog :
http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Where-do-you-deploy-custom-SharePoint-web-service-files-to-%28asmx-discoaspx-and-wsdlaspx%29.aspx which describes the difference between _layouts and _vti_bin.

**Question**
What's the best way to follow ?
And how can this be automated via the build in VS2008 or during deployment from the WSP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the article you reference at the end
>   of your question really answers it:
>   custom web services should be placed
>   in _vti_bin.
>
> i usually start by adding them to
>   _LAYOUTS but thats only to be able to define my discovery files etc (as
>   described in the MSDN specification
>   you mention).

I've created a simple commandline tool which generates *wsdl.aspx and *disco.aspx SharePoint compatible files from the WebService assembly (dll) in the project.

Tool can be found at http://wsdlgenerator.codeplex.com .

When using this in the build from your SharePoint WebServices project like this:

Add the following line to the **"Post Build"** event:

```
"$(ProjectDir)Tools\WSDLGenerator.exe" --input "$(TargetPath)" --outputfolder "$(ProjectDir)12\ISAPI" --spwsdl --spdisco
```

The wsdl and disco files are automatically created and placed in the ISAPI folder.

Answer (score 6):

the article you reference at the end of your question really answers it: custom web services should be placed in _vti_bin.

i usually start by adding them to _LAYOUTS but thats only to be able to define my discovery files etc (as described in the MSDN specification you mention).

_vti_bin is a virtual directory mapped to the 12/ISAPI folder, so you can deploy to that using  element in your solution manifest. See an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543741.aspx)